# How to use Directory.EnumerateFiles

Tags: vb.net

msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

How can I start using the collection before the whole collection is returned?

The following code gives an elapsed time of more than 3 minutes for a directory with around 45000 files

```
Dim TIme1, TIme2 As String
TIme1 = TimeString
Dim DirFiles As Generic.List(Of String) = New Generic.List(Of String)(Directory.EnumerateFiles(SourceDirectory))
Dim NumberOfFiles As Integer
NumberOfFiles = DirFiles.Count()
TIme2 = TimeString
MsgBox("Begin time " & TIme1 & "There are " & NumberOfFiles & " Photos in the Directory ." & SourceDirectory & "End Time " & TIme2)
```

Can I already use entries in Dirfiles before the collection is entirely read? How?

I used to be a professional programmer before Microsoft launched Windows. My experience with windows programming is minimal.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't make good use of count of files returned by `EnumerateFiles`, you can start working with individual files in the collection without any delay with `For Each` loop etc. which don't need the count of elements for its working.

So for example you can do:

```
Dim FileCount As Integer
Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(srcDir)
For Each file in files
    'Do something with this file
    ' e.g.
    TextBox1.AppendText(file & vbCrLf)
    FileCount += 1
Next
MsgBox ( FileCount.ToString & " files processed.")
```

So you see how it can be used?

[NB: freehand typed code..might contain typos. It is only meant to explain the concept.]

Comment: Yes, you can obviously get the count. But the way these two methods work is different. And this post was meant explain exactly that. Enumerables go one item at a time, and if you call the Count method,they would go all the way down to the last item to get the count. It may not have the count stored any where until you actually try to get the count. A List/array on the other hand already has all the items in it, so already has the count too.

Comment: Ok..I think my sentence was confusing... bad english...rephrased it now.

Answer (score 1):

`EnumerateFiles` allows you to **start** processing files before all the files have been found. It appears that you want to know the number of files. You can't know that until all the files have been found, so `EnumerateFiles` doesn't help you in this case.

Comment: `You can't know that until all the files have been found, so EnumerateFiles doesn't help you in this case.`, I would say this isnt a valid statement as GetFiles would be the same, it would still have to create the object and go through the directory before you would know the count (EnumerateFiles doesnt do this). Either way both methods would have to finish before knowing the count. Can you explain?

Comment: EnumerateFiles doesn't help... but it doesn't hurt, either. And it _might_ still help, because now only one file name at a time is loaded in memory, instead of needing to load the entire list.

Comment: @436f6465786572 The question quotes MSDN implying that using `EnumerateFiles` can save time compared to `GetFiles`. I'm simply pointing out that if what you want to do is count the files, `EnumerateFiles` does **not** save time.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for `GetFiles` is `Directory.GetFiles(path As String) As String()`. For it to return you results it must hit the hard drive and build the entire array first. If there are 45,000 files then it must build an array of 45,000 elements before it can give you a result.

The signature for `EnumerateFiles` is `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)`. In this case it doesn't need to hit the hard drive at all to give you a response. So you should be able to get a result almost instantly regardless of the number of files.

Take this test code:

```
Dim sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Windows\System32")
sw.Stop()
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
```

I get a result of about 6.5 milliseconds to return the files.

But if I change `GetFiles` to `EnumerateFiles` I get a result back in 0.07 milliseconds. It's nearly 100 times slower to call `GetFiles` for this folder!

This is because `EnumerateFiles` return an `IEnumerable<string>`. The interface for `IEnumerable(Of T)` is:

```
Public Interface IEnumerable(Of Out T)
    Inherits IEnumerable
    Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of T)
End Interface
```

Whenever we call `foreach` or `.Count()` or `.ToArray()` on an enumerable under the hood we are calling `GetEnumerator()` which in turn returns another object of type `IEnumerator(Of T)` with this signature:

```
Public Interface IEnumerator(Of Out T)
    Inherits IDisposable
    Inherits IEnumerator
    ReadOnly Property Current As T
    Function MoveNext() As Boolean
    Sub Reset()
End Interface
```

It's this enumerator that actually does the hard work of returning all of the files. As soon as the first call to `MoveNext` is made the first file name is immediately available in `Current`. Then `MoveNext` is called in a loop until it returns a `false` and you then know the loop is over. Meanwhile you can collect all of the files from the `Current` property.

So, in your code, if you were performing some action over each and every file returned then `EnumerateFiles` would be the way to go.

But since you are doing `New Generic.List(Of String)(Directory.EnumerateFiles(SourceDirectory))` you are forcing the iteration of the entire enumerable immediately. Any advantage of using `EnumerateFiles` is immediately lost.

Answer (score 0):

GetFiles method will materialize the entire list of files that are in a directory. The preferred method to call now is Directory.EnumerateFiles as it will stream the files back (through a yield-like mechanism) as the underlying call to the OS yields the results back.

Solutions using the GetFiles/GetDirectories are kind of slow since the objects need to be created. Using the enumeration on the other hand doesnt do this, it doesn't create any temporary objects.

Either way in the end theres still iteration happening...

Example file count...

```
 Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, filetype, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I now use the following before enumeratefiles is started

```
Public Function FileCount(PathName As String) As Long
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim fld As Scripting.Folder
    fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FolderExists(PathName) Then
        fld = fso.GetFolder(PathName)
        FileCount = fld.Files.Count
    End If
End Function
```

This needs Microsoft Scripting Runtime (set a reference to the VB script run-time library in your Project)

Comment: This is not an answer. Please delete. To thank people you should upvote their answers and mark one as the accepted answer.